# Как сделать задержку для Модального окна в дискорде?

Tags: python, discord, modal, disnake

Ниже приведён код,в самом конце кода есть блок, который отвечает за вызов модального окна и после, если пользователь нажал кнопку "отправить" на модальном окне, а не закрыл его, то значение перейдёт в другую переменную. Как сделать так, что бы бот дожидался ответа от модального окна, а не шёл сразу дальше? (в данный момент код просто не дожидаясь идет дальше, и когда ты отправляешь модальное окно, то вся информация становиться уже не актуальной, а если ты его закрыл, а не отправил, то снова открыть модальное окно ты уже не сможешь)

```
        view = Button_check(interaction.author, promo)
        message = await channel.send(embed = embed, view=view)
        await view.wait()
        if view.value == True:
            embed.color = 900704
            embed.title = "Заявка одобрена!"
            await message.edit(embed = embed, view = None)
        elif view.value == False:
            embed.color = 0xF34421
            embed.title = "Заявка отклонена!"
            await message.edit(embed = embed, view = None)
            
class DeclineModal(disnake.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self, user: disnake.Member):
        self.user = user
        self.value = Optional[bool]
        self = self
        components = [
            disnake.ui.TextInput(label="Причина отказа", placeholder="Введите причину отказа", custom_id="reason"),
            disnake.ui.TextInput(label="Время тайм-аута", placeholder="Введите время натуральными цифрами (просто цифры, время указывается в часах)", custom_id="time")
            ]
        title = "Отказ"
        super().__init__(title=title, components=components, custom_id="recruitementModal")

    async def callback(self, interaction: disnake.ModalInteraction) -> None:
        reason = interaction.text_values["reason"]
        time = int(interaction.text_values["time"])
        dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=time)
        stampdt = dt.timestamp()
        stdt = round(stampdt)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"<@{interaction.author.id}>, Успешно! Заявка была отказана, а участник был отправлен в тайм-аут на {time} ч", ephemeral=True)
        self.value == True
        
class Button_check(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, user: disnake.Member, promo):
        self.user = user
        self.promo = promo
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.value = Optional[bool]
    @disnake.ui.button(label="Принять",style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def button_accept(self, button:disnake.ui.Button, interaction:disnake.Interaction):
            embed = disnake.Embed(color=0x2F7896, title="Ваша заявка одобрена!")
            embed.description = f">>> Ваша заявка была успешно рассмотрена и одобрена модераторами. Вам были выданы права, которые соответсвуют вашему уровню подписки."
            embed.set_footer(text=interaction.guild.name, icon_url=interaction.guild.icon)
            await self.user.send(embed=embed)
            self.value = True
            self.stop()
        else:
            return
    @disnake.ui.button(label="Отклонить",style=disnake.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def button_decline(self, button:disnake.ui.Button, interaction:disnake.Interaction):
        role = disnake.utils.get(interaction.user.guild.roles, name="")
        role2 = disnake.utils.get(interaction.user.guild.roles, name="")
        if role in interaction.user.roles or role2 in interaction.user.roles:
            modal = DeclineModal(self.user)
            await interaction.response.send_modal(modal)
            if modal.value == True:
                self.value = False
                self.stop()
        else:
            return
```